# How to use a Vertical container in WearOS without issues the BoxedInsetLayout solved?

Tags: wear-os

I am trying to set up a wear os interface using a [vertical container](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/overlays/screens#vertical) and the documentation says:

> Unlike a single screen overlay, don't use BoxInsetLayout. Instead,
> place a ConstraintLayout inside a NestedScrollView. This allows you to
> take advantage of the extra space on the sides of a circular display.

but the text the TextView inside the constraint is impossible to read which seems addressed in [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/overlays/layouts) which says to:

- use a BoxedInsetLayout or a Curved Layout
- Provide alternative layout
  resources for square and round devices

How do you stay away from the complexity of supporting different screen shapes, like the BoxedInsetLayout solved, while using the Vertical container example, which looks great? I wish they would post the code for this example:

[image]